# react router - unable to pass store down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am unable to make the store available to children components.

The setup is a SPA with Symfony as back-end, though this should not make a difference for this matter.

The entry point for Webpack is the file:

*/client/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import Root from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducers from './pages/combine_reducers';

let composeEnhancers = typeof(window) !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
   reducers,
   composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)
   )
)

ReactDOM.render(
     <Root store={store} />
, document.querySelector('#root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

The apps as such is at:

*/client/App.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './pages/home/';
import AccountPage from './pages/account/';


const Root = ({ store }) => {
return(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Link to="/account">Account</Link>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        <div>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/account" component={AccountPage} />
                                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
</Provider>
)
}


Root.propTypes = {
   store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root;
```

So far so good. The store is available in App.js. 
But that's not the case at the next level. As you can see I'm attempting to make the store available using connect().

*/client/pages/home/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Register from '../common/register/';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Home extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     console.log(props);
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Hello World from home! </h1>
                <Register />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
   store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
        store: state.store,
   }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

At the lower level, the Register component, I'm able to submit the form, but the store not being available, I am unable to capture the response coming from the server.

*/client/pages/common/register/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import RegisterForm from './containers/register';
import { actionSubmitRegister } from './actions/';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Register extends React.Component{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           registerResponse: '',
        }
        this.onSubmitRegister = this.onSubmitRegister.bind(this);
    }

onSubmitRegister (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let submitForm = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        actionSubmitRegister(this.props.form.RegisterForm.values);
    });
    submitForm.then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response);
        this.setState({registerResponse:     this.props.submit_register.data});
        console.log('registerResponse', this.state.registerResponse);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

render(){           
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <RegisterForm
                    submitRegister={this.onSubmitRegister}
                />
                <h3>{this.state.registerResponse}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
}
/*
Register.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
*/
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        form: state.form,
        submit_register: state.submit_register,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({actionSubmitRegister}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

Comment: You don't need a store variable separately. The state argument in mapStateToProps is the store instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mapStateToProps` you map `store: state.store` but in general you use this method to map single props from your state to props in your component, not map the entire store (if this is even possible). 
Eg:

`form: state.form`

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan R, but that does not seem to work. The mapStateToProps function on register/index.js does that to submit_register: state.submit_register, but still submit_register does not receive props coming from reducer.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it put me in the rigtht direction. I posted a revised answer for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to access the store object in props is because you are not passing it down via props.
Provider from the react-redux library, makes it available to all children down the element tree. Store is made available via React's context API, NOT via props.

"Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components."

So in a child component of Provider, we can now do something like

```
render() {
 const { store } = this.context;
 console.log(store)
 return(
 ...
 )
}
```

This is the same way that react-redux's connect HOC is able to access the store and subsequently mapStateToProps or utilise the store's dispatch method to mapDispatchToProps.

Also I think Provider requires that it’s child element is a React component.
Check out this [tutorial](https://github.com/tayiorbeii/egghead.io_redux_course_notes/blob/master/20-Passing_the_Store_Down_Implicitly_via_Context.md) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks  @Thomas, but I am still getting undefined for the console.log in your code above.

Comment: @BernardA  can you try changing what is inside your provider tags to be a React component..... that may help

Answer (score 0):

After the input I received above, I reviewed my code and got it to work.

Actually the main issue was on the /client/pages/common/register/index.js file, but I am posting the whole chain for reference:

> /client/index.js

nothing to change

> /client/App.js

The references to propTypes do not seem to be necessary, so I took them out.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
 Link,
 Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './pages/home/';
import AccountPage from './pages/account/';


const Root = ({ store }) => {
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Link to="/account">Account</Link>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        <div>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/account" component={AccountPage} />
                                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
    </Provider>
    )
}

export default Root;
```

> /client/pages/home/index.js

Here both propTypes and connect() do not seem to be required.

```
import React from 'react';
import Register from '../common/register/';

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Hello World from home! </h1>
                <Register />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

> /client/pages/common/register/index.js

The main issue here was the onSubmitRegister() method. The promise was not properly setup and I was referencing the action directly instead of using this.props. React do not seem to like that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import RegisterForm from './containers/register';
import { actionSubmitRegister } from './actions/';

class Register extends React.Component{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            registerResponse: '',
        }
        this.onSubmitRegister = this.onSubmitRegister.bind(this);
    }

onSubmitRegister (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let submitForm = new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(this.props.actionSubmitRegister(this.props.form.RegisterForm.values));
    });
    submitForm.then((result) => {
        let data = result.payload.data;
        this.setState({registerResponse: data.message});
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

render(){           
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <RegisterForm
                    submitRegister={this.onSubmitRegister}
                />
                <h3>{this.state.registerResponse}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        form: state.form,
        submit_register: state.submit_register,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({actionSubmitRegister}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```